# How to Add 7 Authors' Name?

Tags: titles, acm

Hi I have a two columns table with ACM SIG Proceedings template http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates

Here is my code for six authors, my problem is I have a 7-th author, I am not sure how to add it nicely, is it possible to squeeze the second rows(maybe smaller font size) to allow 4 authors?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}
\title{Paper title}


\numberofauthors{6}

\author{

% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 4th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 6th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
}


\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put `\and` after the sixth author to create another row.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}
\title{Paper title}


\numberofauthors{7}

\author{
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 4th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
% 6th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
\and
% 7th. author
\alignauthor
Author Name\\
       \affaddr{This is Author School Name}\\
       \email{AuthorEmail@gmail.com}
}


\maketitle


\end{document}
```

I will advise against squeezing the fourth author into the second row for then it will look cramped. Other options would be to put `\and` after the second and fifth authors or after third and fifth authors. Note that displaying more than six authors after the title is discouraged as posted in [this ACM page](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigguide-v2.2sp).